# How do I use the ADF propertyListener tag?

Tags: java, jsf, oracle-adf

I have a class

```
CustomerBean {
    Customer customer;
    public CustomerBean() {...}
    public getCustomer() {...}
    public void setCustomer(Customer c) {...}
    ...
}
```

When using normal JSF I can use a setPropertyLIstener tag (on say a commandLink) to update the customer property.

I'm trying to do the same thing with Oracle ADF, but failing. How do I specify a binding to a property on a data control? When I try to use Jdeveloper to do it it sets up an iterator for the `customer` variable, how do I declare and wire up a PropertyListener correctly?

Are there any-up-to date ADF resources I should know of? - a lot of ones I come accross use deprecated classes and methods.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

1. From the datacontrol panel, drag the `setCustomer()` method to the page and create it as a command link.
2. Bind the customer argument to `#{requestScope.customer}`.
3. Inside the `commandLink`, use `setPropertyListener`/`setActionListener` to put the customer into request scope.
4. When the `commandLink` is clicked, ADF will pull the customer value from request scope and invoke the method.

Answer (score 0):

How about Oracle's own ADF docs? The `af:setPropertyListener` is specified [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E15523_01/apirefs.1111/e12419/tagdoc/af_setPropertyListener.html).